# .htaccess redirect folder to its subdomain causes redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have a subdomain sub.domain.com
And the same contents are available on domain.com/sub

But now I want to redirect domain.com/sub to sub.domain.com

If I do that with 
Redirect 301 /sub http://sub.domain.com
it causes a redirect loop.

How can this be solved technically? Users should not be able to access the subdomain content under domain.com/sub but should be redirected.

Comment: Can you include your .htaccess content?

Comment: Thanks Maciej, it is just what I wrote in the post: 
Redirect 301 /sub http://sub.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `mod_rewrite` rules here with conditions to restrict the rule only for `domain.com` requests:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub(/.*)?$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Make sure to test this after clearing browser cache.